# Missing Number solution giving incorrect syntax error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, data-structures, ecmascript-6

Trying to solve  Missing Number Problem below

```
            Input: nums = [0,1]
            Output: 2
            Explanation: n = 2 since there are 2 numbers, so all numbers are in the range [0,2]. 2 is the missing number in the range since it does not appear in nums.
```

Its solution giving  incorrect syntax error ,any help in this code,basically constructed array of size n+1, to leave a spot for the missing element. Then Assigned each val to -1 so we can see which position was not filled

```
                let missingNumber = function(nums){


                    const sol =new Array(nums.length+1).fill(-1);
                    
                    for (const num of nums)
                    {
                    sol[num] = num;
                    
                    }
                    
                    return sol.indexOf(-1);



                }

                console.log(missingNumber(5))
```

Error i get is

```
            PS C:\VSB-PRO> node Fibo.js
            C:\VSB-PRO\Fibo.js:5
                const res = new Array(nums.length+1).fill(-1);
                            ^

            RangeError: Invalid array length
                at missingNumber (C:\VSB-PRO\Fibo.js:5:17)
                at Object.<anonymous> (C:\VSB-PRO\Fibo.js:18:13)
                at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
                at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
                at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
                at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
                at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
                at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Your help is appreciated

Regards,

Carolyn

Comment: What does this have to do with TypeScript? Where is the syntax error you are talking about? And why do you think the syntax error is "invalid"? The error you are showing is an ECMAScript error, not TypeScript, it is a range error, not a syntax error, and it is perfectly valid, not invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you were thinking that you were going to pass in an array into your `missingNumber` function as you try to access the `length` property on the parameter. However, you pass in a regular number `5` into the function. This code should fix your issue as I pass in an array instead:

```js
let missingNumber = function(nums) {
  const sol = new Array(nums.length + 1).fill(-1);

  for (const num of nums) {
    sol[num] = num;
  }

  return sol.indexOf(-1);
}

console.log(missingNumber([5, 3, 2, 4]))
```

If that's not what your looking for, then I advise you look over your code to understand where the data is traveling when you pass it into your function in your code.